# Cannot establish Wired connection on Acer Aspire 5930G

Tags: networking, acer, connection, ethernet, wired

I use an Acer Aspire 5930G, dual booted with  Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10.

My problem is that i cannot establish wired connection on my ubuntu.

Wireless connection works in both of my OSs but the Wired connection does not, only on the Ubuntu.

I have already tried the common fix:

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control
```

but without any results.

Any ideas?

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:72:c2:21:a5  
      inet6 addr: fe80::21d:72ff:fec2:21a5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:945 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:204318 (204.3 KB)
      Interrupt:16 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:645874 (645.8 KB)  TX bytes:645874 (645.8 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:ea:57:7b:cc  
      inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::216:eaff:fe57:7bcc/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:19937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:10877245 (10.8 MB)  TX bytes:3131378 (3.1 MB)

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8071 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
```

Comment: can you list the output of 'lspci' , or shorter, 'lspci | grep Ethernet' ? (don't type the ' )

Comment: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8071 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)

Comment: 'lsmod | grep sk98lin' should show that the loadable kernel module sk98lin is installed. If not, see the information on marvell.com to download and install the appropriate driver (as a loadable kernel module)

Comment: Thanks for everything Frank! But today out of the sudden the Ethernet connection was established during the boot. I still have no clue why it couldn't be done the past days but now it works and for now I don't have any issue with is.I surely hope it will remain that way. Anyway thanks for your time!